# How to do scattering2D of an image file?

Tags: wavelet

I am trying to do wavelet scattering of a 2d image with the following code:

```
#import torch
from kymatio import Scattering2D
import numpy as np
import PIL
from PIL import Image

FILENAME = "./square.png"
image = PIL.Image.open(FILENAME).convert("L")

a = np.array(image).astype(np.float64)
x = torch.from_numpy(a)
imageSize = x.shape

print( imageSize )

scattering = Scattering2D(J=2, shape=imageSize, frontend='numpy', L=8)

Sx = scattering(x)

print(Sx.size())
```

and get the following error messages. Can anyone help?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/pminev/Desktop/scatter2d.py", line 18, in 
Sx = scattering(x)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kymatio/frontend/torch_frontend.py", line 22, in forward
return self.scattering(x)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kymatio/scattering2d/frontend/torch_frontend.py", line 98, in scattering
S = scattering2d(input, self.pad, self.unpad, self.backend, self.J,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kymatio/scattering2d/core/scattering2d.py", line 19, in scattering2d
U_1_c = cdgmm(U_0_c, phi['levels'][0])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kymatio/backend/torch_backend.py", line 192, in cdgmm
raise TypeError('Input and filter must be of the same dtype.')
TypeError: Input and filter must be of the same dtype.

Trying to do wavelet scattering of of an image.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the kymatio call to numpy like that.
The use of torch seems to be the problem

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import kymatio.numpy as kp

# Example image (2D array)
FILENAME = "./square.png"
pil_img = PIL.Image.open(FILENAME).convert("L")
img = np.array(pil_img).astype(float)

# Define wavelet scattering parameters
J = 2  # Number of scales
L = 8  # Number of angles
image_size = img.shape[0]

# Compute wavelet scattering transform
scattering = kp.Scattering2D(J=J, shape=(image_size, image_size), L=L)
scattering_coeffs = scattering(img)

# Plot the original image
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Original Image')
plt.axis('off')

# Plot the first-order scattering coefficients
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.imshow(scattering_coeffs[1], cmap='viridis')
plt.title('First-order Scattering Coefficients')
plt.axis('off')

# Plot the second-order scattering coefficients
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.imshow(scattering_coeffs[2], cmap='viridis')
plt.title('Second-order Scattering Coefficients')
plt.axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```